# Which of the two structs is best to use in general?

Tags: c++, struct

I agree that the struct with the static function is much easier to use, however I always receive advice that static functions and/or variables shouldn't really be used.

```
struct Factorial_Local
{
    size_t factorial(size_t n)
    {
        size_t fact = 1;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            fact *= i;

        return fact;
    }
};

struct Factorial_Static
{
    static size_t factorial(size_t n)
    {
        size_t fact = 1;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            fact *= i;

        return fact;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Exemple of usage with both structs

    cout << Factorial_Local().factorial(5) << endl;
    cout << Factorial_Static::factorial(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. C != C++, 2. what is wrong with a simple function declaration? 3. you forgot namespace option

Comment: `I always receive advice that static functions and/or variables shouldn't really be used` I don't know where you got that advice but its questionable, if a static method is the right approach for a problem then use it

Comment: If you have a `class` or `struct` that has _only_ static functions you could also make it a namespace. But I don't think there's any objective answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is opinion based, so someone will probably close it, but...

Your trivial example is pretty. Using a namespace is better for this. Use non-static methods when they really work on an instance of your object. Use static methods when they're truly related to the class of object.

And use namespaces when you're just trying to organize methods.